# Having issues with if and while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(query_results)) !=0)

Tags: mysql, c

For some reason my C code does not work. The SQL code is correct, when I run it into phpmyadmin I get the results I need, but if I run this code it seems to come up empty. Now interesting part is if I remove the

```
if((row = mysql_fetch_row(query_results)) !=0)
```

Then the while loops works, or if I remove the

```
        while((row = mysql_fetch_row(query_results)) !=0)
```

Then I am able to get results. Not sure why those two cannot work together, yet separately  they both work fine.

```
    MYSQL_RES *query_results = mysql_store_result(conn);

    if (query_results) 
    { // make sure there *are* results..
        MYSQL_ROW row;

        if((row = mysql_fetch_row(query_results)) !=0)
        {

            while((row = mysql_fetch_row(query_results)) !=0)
            {

                printf("So far soo good 2\n");

                /* Set a float 'f' to the value in 'row[0]', or
                * 0.0f if it's NULL */  
                char *result_miner =  row[0] ? row[0] : "NULL";
                char *result_algorithm =  row[1] ? row[1] : "NULL";
                char *result_url =  row[2] ? row[2] : "NULL";
                int result_port = row[3] ? atof(row[3]) : 1;    
                char *result_username =  row[4] ? row[4] : "NULL";
                char *result_password =  row[5] ? row[5] : "NULL";

                strcpy(miner, result_miner);
                strcpy(algorithm, result_algorithm);
                strcpy(url, result_url);
                strcpy(username, result_username);
                strcpy(password, result_password);
                port=result_port;


                    printf ("Miner Protocol is: %s\n", miner);
                    printf ("Algorithm is: %s\n", algorithm);
                    printf ("Mining URL  is: %s\n", url);
                    printf ("Mining Port is: %d \n", port);
                    printf ("Username is: %s \n", username);
                    printf ("Password is: %s \n", password);


            }


        }else{

            printf("Unable to locate active coin for hostname: %s", hostname);
            exit (-1);

            }

    /* Free results when done */
    mysql_free_result(query_results);
```

Comment: What does it mean "it doesn't work"?

Comment: The results seem to come up empty, as you can see I am using printf to output the results, and they are blank

Comment: How many rows do you expect? The `if((row = mysql_fetch_row(...)` line should only have the effect that the first row is not printed. And when you say *come up empty*, you mean the output is `"Miner Protocol is: "` or that there is no output at all?

Comment: Since `mysql_fetch_row` does not have an argument for _which_ row; I can only assume that it comsumes the current row and/or advances to the next row. If you call it in the `if` and the `where` with only one row in the result, one of the two conditions will not get a row. (or to put it more succinctly like Pablo, you are always throwing away your first row).

Comment: @Pablo, for now I am expecting 1 row, and yes the result is :    "Miner Protocol is: ".

Comment: @Vlad since you need the if for it's else, try changing your `while` to a `do...while`.

Comment: @Uueerdo will a do..while be able to catch if there is no results returned? I want to be able to let me know if the results come up empty. Hence, why I out the if in front of it.

Comment: If you are expecting one row, then it is consumed in the `if(...)` line. The next time you call `mysql_fetch_row` you should get an error value. Check the API documentation and see which value `mysql_fetch_row` returns when you call it after all rows have been fetched.

Comment: @Pablo is there a way to have an if statement as well as a while loop for the results?

Comment: I was suggesting use `if (x) { do { } while(x);}` so the first iteration uses the row from the `if`.

Comment: Can you please provide me with some example code please?

Comment: @Uueerdo I see no point in doing that, `while(mysql_fetch_row(...))` does that anyway. It's also how the documentation says you should do. The problem here seems to be that the OP doesn't realize that he/she is throwing away the first row with the `if`.

Comment: @Pablo he has an `else` case; that won't work with a `while` without adding a variable to track "rowsProcessed", and changing the `else` to an `if (rowsProcessed)`. _Your "num_rows" answer is probably the best, I was just pointing toward the "least changes" to existing code._

Comment: I removed the else, and put `if else` , based on the number that it returns it will either run or do something.

Comment: @Uueerdo oh yes, I didn't scroll down enough to notice that. The proper way to look if there are any results, is to use `mysql_num_rows` like I wrote in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [reference page of `mysql_fetch_row`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-fetch-row.html), you would have to do
this:

```
while((row = mysql_fetch_row(query_results)))
{
    printf("So far soo good 2\n");

    char *result_miner =  row[0] ? row[0] : "NULL";
    char *result_algorithm =  row[1] ? row[1] : "NULL";
    char *result_url =  row[2] ? row[2] : "NULL";
    int result_port = row[3] ? atof(row[3]) : 1;    
    char *result_username =  row[4] ? row[4] : "NULL";
    char *result_password =  row[5] ? row[5] : "NULL";
    ....
}
```

There is no need to add to put the `while` inside the `if((row = mysql_fetch_row(query_results)) !=0)`, as it will consume one
row and if you say you expect one row only, then this explains why you are
seeing no values.

The documentation says that if no more row can be fetch, `mysql_fetch_row` will
return `NULL`. You say you expect 1 row, but it could be that you get 2 rows
where one has empty values. Before the `while` loop you can use
[`mysql_num_rows()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-num-rows.html) to see the actual number of rows in the result set. I
suspect that your query results in 2 rows.

> *[`mysql_num_rows()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-num-rows.html)*
>
> ```
>  my_ulonglong mysql_num_rows(MYSQL_RES *result)
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> Returns the number of rows in the result set.
>
> The use of `mysql_num_rows()` depends on whether you use `mysql_store_result()` or `mysql_use_result()` to return the result set.
>   **If you use `mysql_store_result()`, `mysql_num_rows()` may be called immediately.** If you use `mysql_use_result()`, `mysql_num_rows()` does not return the correct value until all the rows in the result set have been retrieved.

---

**edit**

How to use `mysql_num_rows`.

```
MYSQL_RES *query_results = mysql_store_result(conn);

if(query_results)
{
    printf ("Number of rows: %lu\n",
            (unsigned long) mysql_num_rows(query_results));

    while((row = mysql_fetch_row(query_results)))
        ...
}
```

See also [`my_ulonglong` 27.8.5 C API Data Structures](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/c-api-data-structures.html#idm140136384379424).

Comment: Thank you, can you give me an example with the num_rows please? Never used that function, I am using mysql_store_result().

Comment: I've made an update of my answer. You have to read the documentation, I've never used the C interface of MySQL, but I find the documentation pretty clear and easy to follow.

Comment: Thank you I think I got it, I can now use the num_rows functions to compare the output and go from there

Comment: Yes, you should do that, I suspect that your query returns more than one row.